# Calculate iterated limits of $f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{x} \sin(x y), & x \neq 0 \\ y, & x=0\end{array}\right.$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

For the following functions calculate the one-dimensional iterated limits $\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\left[\lim _{y \rightarrow y_{0}} f(x, y)\right]$ and $\lim _{y \rightarrow y_{0}}\left[\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x, y)\right]$ and the two-dimensional limit $\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)} f(x, y)$

$\lim _{x \rightarrow x_{0}}\left[\lim _{y \rightarrow y_{0}} f(x, y)\right]$
So I do:

$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left[\lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x} \sin(x y)\right]=0$

And

$\lim _{y \rightarrow 0}\left[\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x} \sin(x y)\right]=0$

and then when $y=mx$

$\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow\left(0, mx\right)} \frac{1}{x} \sin(x y)=0$

But I'm confused in the part when says $0$ if $x=y$ what should I do

Comment: What is "sen"? Can you clarify?

Comment: @paulgarrett In some regions, "sen" is used instead of "sine" or "sin".

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thanks! Somehow I'd never heard about this, despite reading mathematics in several different languages...

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes, is sin :D

Comment: when $x\neq0$, $f(x,y)=y\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}$. and so $|f(x,y)|\leq |y|$ for all $(x,y)$. So the limit as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ is $0$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes (0,0)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment:

When $x\neq0$, $f(x,y)=y\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}$ and so, $|f(x,y)|\leq |y|$ for all $(x,y)$. So the limit as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ is $0$, that is

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)=0$$

Comment: Thank you! then my process is all wrong? what happened when $x=y$

Comment: for the double limit it should not matter how you approximate $(0,0)$. Going along a line is not enough to find the double limit.

Answer (score 0):

For the two dimensional limit we have that for $x\neq 0$

$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}\sin(x y)=y\frac{\sin(x y)}{xy} \to 0 \cdot 1 =0$$

and for $x=0$

$$f(x,y)=y \to 0$$